# Why in C does taking input using int format to a char change the value of another char variable?

Tags: c, char, integer, scanf

I took input in `%d` format into a character using `scanf()` because I didn't want more than 8 bits. But doing so changed the value of another char variable.

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char a;
        char b;
        printf("Enter a: ");
        scanf("%c", &a);
        printf("a = %c\n", a);
        printf("Enter b: ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        printf("\na = %d\n", a);
        printf("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a: c
a = c
Enter b: 56

a = 0
b = 56
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0431k.jpg)

Comment: You have to decide what you want to read. Do you want to read a single character (and store it as a char) or do you want to read an integer (and store it as an int)? You chose to read chars (`char a;char b;`). So using `%d` as format specifier doesn't make sense. Also, using `56` as input doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

```
scanf("%d", &b);
```

With %d you are storing an integer into the char variable that can not hold an integer.
the Variable now grows into the other variable in stack above it.

if you compile with the flag "-fstack-protector-all" you should get the
*** stack smashing detected *** error on execution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the side effect you indicated. This happens when the compiler loads variables in memory one after the other. For example, I examined the change in variable a when a sufficiently large number is typed in variable b. I changed the code as follows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char a, b;
    printf( "Address (a): %p\tAddress(b): %p\n", &a, &b);

    printf( "Enter the values (a, b): " );
    scanf( "%c, %d", &a, &b);
    printf( "Value (a): %d\tValue (b): %d\n", a, b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then, when I tested the code, I realized the consequences of this side effect.

[image]

The tested code is interpreted in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formatting directives in a `scanf` format string indicate not just how to match the input, but also the type of the corresponding variable in which the resulting value is to be stored.  If you pass a pointer to an object of a different type than the corresponding directive expects then you reap undefined behavior.

That's true even for a simple signedness mismatch, but in your case you have a size mismatch.  For a `%d` directive without a size modifier, `scanf` expects to write the scanned integer value in an object of type [`signed`] `int`.  If the pointer you pass instead points to a `char`, and if, as is the case in most implementations, `int` is larger than `char`, then it is particularly likely that the resulting undefined behavior manifests in unwanted ways, such as by producing changes in the values of other variables.

If you want to scan a number as a `char`-sized integer, then you should

1. Declare the variable as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, not default `char`, and
2. Use the correct conversion specifier *and size modifier* for the chosen data type.

For example,

```
unsigned char b;

scanf("%hhu", &b);
```

`%u` is the format directive for an unsigned integer, and the `hh` modifier instructs `scanf` that the destination variable is the size of a `char` / `signed char` / `unsigned char`.

If you want a signed integer then it would be similar, but with the `%d` formatting directive:

```
signed char b;

scanf("%hhd", &b);
```

As a matter of style, do not use default `char` for numeric data, even if you are confident that the range of values you need to support is a subset of the intersection of the ranges of `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  Especially so if you plan to use it with formatted I/O functions, because it is implementation-specific whether `%hhd` or `%hhu` is the correct directive for a default `char`.